# Can I marry an atheist woman with our parents' consent? What if she's pregnant?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, baby

If I am in a relationship with an atheist woman, then what should I do, leave her or marry her?

If I tell her I can't marry her because she is an atheist, she might lie about her beliefs. If she is pregnant (less then 2 months) and she decides to keep the baby then what should my decision be based to Islam?

If both her and my parents consent to this marriage, is it ok to marry her?

Comment: It's haram to date so you shouldn't even be with a relationship with any women, regardless is she is Muslim or not and if she is pregnant, then you committed zina which is even worse of a sin.

Comment: If you tell her that you cannot marry her because she is an atheist, she is more likely to be really mad at you than make up fake beliefs in two minutes. She might propose to fake beliefs in front of your parents, though. This is quite common regardless of marriage when the older generations are not comfortable with atheism.

Comment: Brother I strongly​ warn you against marrying non Muslim woman, although it's your decision.. but that's my advice.. think about your children's fate it's not worth it, Allah SWT says by the interpretation of the meaning " slave woman who believes is better than an unbelieving woman, even though she allures you." Qur'an 2:221 ...

Answer (score 7):

Islam only allows marriage to a Muslim, a Jew or a Christian.

> [Quran 60:10](https://quran.com/60/10) ... And hold not to marriage bonds with disbelieving
>   women ...
>
> [Quran 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5) ... And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from
>   among the believers and chaste women from among those who were given
>   the Scripture before you ...

The parents' consent and the pregnancy do not have any bearing on the ruling.

You should also know that sexual relations outside of marriage is *Zina* (fornication), it is itself a major sin and a punishable crime under shariah.

> [Quran 17:32](https://quran.com/17/32) And do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse.
>   Indeed, it is ever an immorality and is evil as a way.
>
> [Quran 24:33](https://quran.com/24/33) But let them who find not [the means for] marriage
>   abstain [from sexual relations] until Allah enriches them from His
>   bounty ...
>
> [Quran 23:5-7](https://quran.com/23/5-7) And they who guard their private parts. Except from
>   their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they will
>   not be blamed. But whoever seeks beyond that, then those are the
>   transgressors.

Comment: can you also comment about the pregnancy?

Comment: @Honey I mentioned that the child wouldn't have bearing on the impermissibility, I didn't initially comment on the Zina aspect, but yes I guess I should have.  Was there something else on your mind?

Comment: I'm just not sure if he means she was pregnant from a previous marriage or not, but if it was from a previous marriage then assuming she converts...does he have to wait? How long?

Comment: @Honey The iddat for a pregnant woman ends when she delivers [65:4](https://quran.com/65/4). In the case of zina with another man, among the Hanafis some allow marriage but not intercourse before the delivery.

Answer (score -1):

Convert her to Islam and go for marriage. Even if she is not believing properly inside herself, it is acceptable to consider her as a Muslim and make the marriage. Islam is easy and Slowly convince her to Islam. As she is pregnant already do some prayer for the forgiveness of committing sex sin.

Don't think complex. Islam is easy.

Answer (score -2):

If you're worried that marrying her is a sin you realize the quran is quite clear that once a child is conceived, it has the right to life.  The Quran makes it very clear that all life is sacred.  It is never permissible to terminate a pregnancy because one fears being unable to financially support a child or another child. It is God, who is the Provider and Sustainer of all life.

Furthmore Prophet Muhammad was heard to say, “A woman may be married for four reasons: her wealth, her lineage, her beauty, and her religious commitment.  Marry the one who is religiously committed.”

Looking at the situation, she has a choice to make whether SHE wants to marry you, assuming she did you could rationalize it would be for her lineage and yours. However, I dont see how youre so comfortable committing adultry and simultaneous concerned whether or not it would be proper to marry the mother of your child?

Comment: "It is never permissible to terminate a pregnancy because one fears being unable to financially support a child or another child." I'm not aware of any scholars who outright declare abortion haram; overall this post reads like opinion without representing any Islamic point of view.